# Can pointers be used with Dictionary<TKey,TSource>?

Tags: c#, pointers

Let's say I have the following class:

```
    public class MyClass {
    public string FirstAttribute {
        get {
            return Attributes["FirstAttribute"];
        }
        set {
            Attributes["FirstAttribute"] = value;
        }
    }
    public string SecondAttribute {
        get {
            return Attributes["SecondAttribute"];
        }
        set {
            Attributes["SecondAttribute"] = value;
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes;
    public MyClass(Dictionary<string,string> att) {
        Attributes = att;
    }
}
```

and I wanted to be able to obtain a pointer to the value that is stored in the Dictionary, so that I can get and set the values (yes unsafe) directly without having to wait for the Dictionary to search for the element by key every time.

Is there a way to do that in c#?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem?

Comment: The Dictionary could contain thousands of items, as custom fields; so there could be a performance problem. I considered using an List<string> and an index, however that would mean that they would have to load in a particular order.

Comment: what makes you think that the Dictionary gets slower just because you stick thousands of items there? Dictionary has ammortized `O(1)` lookup.
To be frank, you don't need to worry until you have measured that this is actually a big problem of yours.

Comment: Would you happen to know the search method used for the lookup?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) notes "Hash table", "O(1)", etc. The exact implementation can be extracted using [IL Spy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) or Reflector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe so. You could store a mutable wrapper in the dictionary though:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then create the dictionary (which should be private, by the way - public fields are a really bad idea other than for constants) as a `Dictionary<string, Wrapper<string>>`. You can then keep fields for the `Wrapper<string>` objects associated with `"FirstAttribute"` and `"SecondAttribute"`.

Frankly I don't think this would be a particularly good idea - I'd just stick with the dictionary lookup - but it's an option. (Assuming nothing's going to change which wrapper is associated with the keys.)

Another option is simply to use fields for the two specific attributes - when you're asked to set a new value, set it in the dictionary *and* set a field. When you're asked for the current value, just return the value from the field. Of course, that's assuming that you're in control of the dictionary (i.e. so it can't change outside your class).

Comment: So, what you're saying is to wrap the value in an object and then get the reference to that object?

Comment: @kurtnelle: I'm not saying you *should* do that - I'm saying you *could* do that. So the dictionary value will be a container, not the string itself. You can then change what's in that container.

Answer (score 1):

No, no, no, no.

`string`s are immutable for a reason. A `string` might be shared between multiple references: modifying it directly with unsafe code might lead to weird behavior.

A way to go around this would be to write a wrapper class that olds your value, and keep a reference to an instance of that wrapper. The getters and setters would then modify the wrapper's property.

Comment: So wrapping the string in an object would be the best way.

Comment: Therefore technically I should be able to get a reference to the KeyValuePair for this purpose. correct?

Comment: `KeyValuePair` is a value type. You can't get a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the dictionary were mutable, you could grab the reference to them and mutate them. But strings are immutable. So the dictionary has its own copy of a reference to your string, and you can't alter the string it is pointing to. If you try to replace it with another string, you need to update the dictionary with the new reference. So basically there's no way to improve on what you have in this situation.